# Best way to storage files in MySQL server

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access-2010, attachment

I have:

1. Back-end: MySQL
2. Front-end: MS Access 2010
3. ODBC Connector

Right now I use bound forms for adding new records, however the "Attachment" feature from Access databases I can't use it because my back-end is MySQL. I need to storage small files (30kb) in one field of a table.

Is there any simple way to do it? I've been working on it for days, but I couldn't find a work around.

Comment: Why don't you store the file on the filesystem, and put the location in the MySQL db?

Comment: Besides using the filesystem, there is the BLOB field type.  It is a bit harder to use in programming APIs, but it is straightforward enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store files in MySQL the better type of column is [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

If are going to store small files (~30KB) is fine, but if you want to store [bigger files](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database) or a lot of them you [should not](http://blog.lick-me.org/2013/01/repeat-after-me-mysql-is-not-a-filesystem/) store these files in the MySQL database.

I personally prefer to store the files in a cloud file storage server like [RIAK CS](http://basho.com/riak-cloud-storage/) or [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). I just store the location of the file in the database.

Comment: Thank you Rafa. I finally implemented an FTP in the form by opening a shell and uploading the file to the server. Afterwards I store the path of the file in the database.
I guess it's the most logical way of doing this, however now is difficult to control whether the file has been successfully updated,  since there is no communication between the 'shell' and the form in Access.